# Compiling QSerialPort on OSX SnowLeopard and QT 4.8

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt4, qtserialport

I installed `qt 4.8` on my `Osx Snow Leopard`, I had cloned `QtSerialPort` from  `git://gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport.git` and then I tried to build it in `QtCreator`.

When I try to build the library I am receiving the following error:
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp:62:34: error: private/qcore_unix_p.h: No such file or directory
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp: In member function 'bool QSerialPortPrivate::open(QFlags)':
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp:218: error: 'qt_safe_open' was not declared in this scope
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp: In member function 'void QSerialPortPrivate::close()':
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp:309: error: 'qt_safe_close' was not declared in this scope
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp: In member function 'qint64 QSerialPortPrivate::readFromPort(char*, qint64)':
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp:1081: error: 'qt_safe_read' was not declared in this scope
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp: In member function 'qint64 QSerialPortPrivate::writeToPort(const char*, qint64)':
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp:1097: error: 'qt_safe_write' was not declared in this scope
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp: In member function 'qint64 QSerialPortPrivate::writePerChar(const char*, qint64)':
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp:1134: error: 'qt_safe_write' was not declared in this scope
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp: In member function 'qint64 QSerialPortPrivate::readPerChar(char*, qint64)':
    /Users/warcomeb/Projects/External/qserial/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_unix.cpp:1160: error: 'qt_safe_read' was not declared in this scope
    make[2]: *** [qserialport_unix.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [sub-serialport-make_default] Error 2
    make: *** [sub-src-make_default-ordered] Error 2
    14:45:11: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
    Error while building/deploying project qtserialport (kit: Desktop)

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Repository was recently breaked for Qt 4. Please wait for fix ( https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,77978 ) merged and then update your clone.

Answer (score 0):

Basically as Sergey wrote.

I accidentally approved two changes from someone else without testing the change on Qt 4 and contributors usually test the patches only against Qt 5, except us.

Once I realized that it would break the repository, I [submitted a revert](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,77978) for those changes, and then I [re-pushed the change](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,78278) with some fixes to work with both Qt 4 and 5.

This should now be fixed both in the "stable" (default) and "dev" branch, so all you need to do is `git pull` to get in unbroken again.